# How do I switch windows with the selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium, popup, window, selenium-webdriver

The instruction here:

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html

say "In Selenium 2(WebDriver), testing popup windows involve switching the driver to the popup window and then running the corresponding actions. "

I am using the selenium IDE to build and run my test cases.
Where exactly do I put the above java code?

I cannot modify the source code myself but I can do whatever I want in Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that is mentioned in the link - it's pure Java. You don't need to do any modifications of your site JavaScript if you want to switch between windows. You can do do any test automation using WebDriver library.

`browser` is an instance of `WebDriver` class and it has `switchTo()` method. In other binding languages (C#, Ruby, Python) there are similar methods for the same purpose.

Comment: In what language are you writing tests using WebDriver?

Comment: I'm using the selenium IDE to log, modify and write them with commands like open, clickAndWait and Store and finding stuff with xpath

Comment: That's completely changes the question. You are using Selenium IDE and there is nothing common between Selenium IDE and WebDriver. The only thing - you can generate (export) code from Selenium IDE script to Java, C# (and something else) and exported code should work with WebDriver library. Coming back to the initial question of Window selection - use "selectWindow" command.

Comment: How can I deal with the fact that the new window isn't named?

Comment: You can use other ways to identify window (e.g. title: title=<your title>). In the help to "selectWindow" it's written _Window locators provide different ways of specifying the window object: by title, by internal JavaScript "name," or by JavaScript variable._

Answer (score 0):

**Whenever you click on a link that opens a new window or even when you open a new window by your own code**,You can use the code given in the link to select the window and perform any operation in that window.

You have nothing to do with the source code.The code given will serve all the purpose.

Comment: How do I "use the code"?  I do not know java.  Where do I put the code? Question remains

Comment: Could you please show us a little bit of code that you have tried?The code which opens a new window?